# Does the svc file for a WCF always need anonymous access?

Tags: wcf

Is it **necessary to allow anonymous access for a svc file when hosting WCF in IIS** 7.5? If yes, then why is such an access needed?

**LATEST UPDATE**
***I found that svc doesn't need anonymous access.*** I think I was getting an error that seemed to be related to svc but wasn't. I am using the following security for the hosting website in IIS 7.5.

```
<security>
  <authentication>
    <anonymousAuthentication enabled="false" />
    <basicAuthentication enabled="true" /> 
    <windowsAuthentication enabled="true" />
  </authentication>
</security>
```

Comment: No, it depends on your configuration. Can you give more details on the problems you're having?

Comment: Our tech services is saying that when hosting WCF in IIS 7.5, svc file should never be allowed anonymous access. If we do not enable anonymous access to svc, then I get an error when calling WCF web service method from a client.

Comment: I looked at these links: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd632740.aspx
http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/eu/wcf/thread/ae2f0a9b-8f13-4452-88ac-48a033065cc3

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff405740.aspx is a better source for this

Comment: I still think when hosting WCF in IIS 7.7 we need to have the svc file with anonymous access. I just want an answer to this question?

Comment: What other kind of access have you tried? Exactly what error do you receive, and exactly when do you receive it?

Comment: Sorry. Somehow its started to work now. So I have anonymous authentication disabled, and it doesn't throw an error.  I use the security for host web site as under Latest Update in my initial post. Thanks.

Comment: Voltagex, Can you post, so I can mark your post as my answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer, thanks to Voltagex. This answer is explained under **LATEST UPDATE** in my initial post. However, I am mentioning it here also.

**I found that svc doesn't need anonymous access.** I think I was getting an error that seemed to be related to svc but wasn't. I am using the following security for the hosting website in IIS 7.5. SVC access is closely related to the security you have specified for the website hosting your WCF. In my case, I used the following security for the hosting website, where I needed to turn off anonymous access and allow only authenticated users to access the host website file resources like svc files.

```
<security>
 <authentication>
  <anonymousAuthentication enabled="false" />
  <basicAuthentication enabled="true" /> 
  <windowsAuthentication enabled="true" />
 </authentication>
</security>
```